# How can I convert a single column of an array of Active Record objects into an array of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an array of rails ActiveRecord objects, and I need to extract a single string column into an array.  Is there an easy way to get ActiveRecord to return my simple array without writing a loop?

Currently I have:

```
myObjects = MyObject.all
myArray = []
myObjects.each do |obj|
  myArray << obj.field_name
end
```

I'd like to have something like:

```
myArray = MyObject.all.give_me_the_array_of(:field_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pluck

```
MyObject.pluck(:field_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following one liner should work:

```
myArray = MyObject.all.map{|a| a.field_name}
```